# Connecting two agents of an agent based model in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to connect two agents in AnyLogic for my agent based model. Can someone please tell me how to do that ?

I tried some of the literature available at (https://anylogic.help/anylogic/interaction/index.html). But it didnot help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Connections types, either single or collection of links depend on the links settings inside your agent and this in turn isset by the space and environment settings where you agents live.

[image]

[image]

You can connect two agents using `connectTo(Agent a)` and disconnect using `disconnect()` (which will disconnect from all connected agents) and get the connected agent using `getConnectedAgent()`

If you connected multiple agents to each other you can use  `LinkedList<Agent> getConnections()` to get all the agents it is connected to.

Read more [here](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/agentbased/link.html#managing-connections-dynamically)

Check out [this model](https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/ce6c8f39-718c-4e23-9be2-7ed73d770157?mode=SETTINGS&tab=GENERAL) on the cloud and the details of the example [here](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/agentbased/connections-and-networks.html#manage-connections-dynamically)